# How can one test Laravel nova actions?

Tags: laravel, phpunit, laravel-nova

I have made a laravel nova application with many resources. Most of these resources have a nova action attached to them.

How can I unit test Laravel nova actions?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I use a package that helps me a lot:

[nova-assertions](https://github.com/dillingham/nova-assertions)